# How to get url data in html textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a simple code of javascript which displays text from url.
example: index.html?id=001
then its output displays in html page as 001. but i want that data (id=001) into html text box which display only "001" into textbox.

here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GET() {
var data = [];
for(x = 0; x < arguments.length; ++x)
data.push(location.href.match(new RegExp("/\?".concat(arguments[x],"=","([^\n&]*)")))[1])
return data;
}
</script>

<br />
<script type="text/javascript"> document.write(GET("id")[0]); </script>
<br /><br />
<input type="text" id="" value="" name="" />
```

Actually i want that "001" into textbox as a textbox value.

Comment: why not try: `document.write("id="+GET("id")[0]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are probably overkill for this, and your expression will only find the querystring value if it immediately follows the ?.

You should use location.search rather than the full URL, because then you just need to take everything after the first character (which will be ? if there is anything), and it will eliminate hashes.

I used simple string splitting to create a reusable map of key/value pairs for lookup.

```js
function GET() {
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    data.push(getQueryMap()[arguments[i]]);
  }
  return data;
}

var queryMap = null;
function getQueryMap() {
  if (queryMap) { return queryMap; }
  queryMap = {};
  var querySplit = location.search.substring(1).split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < querySplit.length; i++) {
    var thisQuery = querySplit[i].split('=', 2);
    queryMap[thisQuery[0]] = thisQuery[1];
  }
  return queryMap;
}
```

To use the input and get the value into it, you need an ID on it or another way to identify it:

```html
<input type="text" id="someInput" value="" name="" />
```

Then, after it, put a script like so:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('someInput').value = GET('id')[0];  
</script>
```

Comment: My mistake. I had a bug in the code I gave you. I have edited it and tested it to ensure it works correctly.

Comment: yeah its working now :) thanks sir :) but if parameter is "index.html" only then its shows "undefined". i mean text is not empty if value inst "index.html?id=001". but i m still thanksful that ur code works too :)

Comment: Easiest fix for that would be during your assignment to check for null/undefined and replace with blank: `GET('id')[0] || ''`.

Answer (score 2):

Put the script after the input then just set its value:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" value="" name="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function GET() {
  var data = [];
  for(x = 0; x < arguments.length; ++x)
     data.push(location.href.match(new RegExp("(/\?id=)([^\&]*)"))[2]);
     return data;
  }
  document.getElementById('myInput').value = (GET("id")[0]); 
</script>
```

Comment: did you add the id="myInput" on the html tag?

Comment: yeah i copied same your code and run it but its shows blank textbox

Comment: I assumed your regex was already working,. I just updated my answer with a regex that works. Though, as others here have said there are better ways to retrieve a querystring parameter in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Replace...

`<script type="text/javascript"> document.write(GET("id")[0]); </script>`

with...

`<script type="text/javascript">$('input').val(GET("id")[0]);</script>`

Place that line **after** the `input` box.

Comment: This would require jquey.

Comment: Yes, what's the problem? The question is tagged as jquery.

Comment: i want url data into html textbox

Comment: Yes, you want 001 into the text box. That's what my code does.

Comment: do i need jquery to run it ?

Comment: Yes, you need jQuery to run it. You tagged your question with `jquery` so I guessed you were fine with that.

Comment: @VicenteOlivertRiera you are right, did not see that.

Comment: @PravinParmar you don't need that. Actually the first answer is vanilla

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of functions that help you parse a URL's parameters into an associative array.

```
function transformToAssocArray(prmstr) {
    var arr = {};
    var prmarr = prmstr.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < prmarr.length; i++) {
        var tmparr = prmarr[i].split("=");
        arr[tmparr[0]] = tmparr[1];
    }
    return arr;
}

function getURLParmeters() {
    var prmstr = window.location.search.substr(1);
    if (prmstr === null || prmstr === '' ) {
        return null;
    }
    return transformToAssocArray(prmstr);
}
```

Then you can assign all URL parameters to a variable like this:

```
var params = getURLParameters();
```

From then on, you can access the parameter's value by referencing `params.paramternamehere`. So, to assign the value of the "id" parameter to a text input, just grab that input element and assign `params.id` to that input's value.

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById("myTextInput");
if (params !== null) {
    inputElement.value = params.id;
}
```

This technique utilizes the [`HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/search) property to reliably separate URL location components from paramters, and then does a simple string [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to separate key-value pairs and then store those pairs in an associative array.